# How to set custom routing for ASP NET CORE Identity 2.1 , extending class libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I have an application that only does log in. its part of a multi-subdomain app.

```
sub1.domain.com
sub2.domain.com
login.domain.com
```

we send users to login domain for authentication. To make the url simple we always had the login page set as home page. after upgrading to the new identity 2.1, we have problem setting our routing for identity.

i have tried putting routing on

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("")]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
```

also i tried

```
[Route("")]
public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
```

but i dont get a result.
Any idea how to set the identity url.

the current default url right now is

```
/identity/account/login
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just a quick thing to check. Is it happening because you have the new cookie consent feature turned on? I wrote about it here: https://jdono.com/2018/05/31/asp-net-core-2-1-0-individual-authentication-issues-after-migrating-from-2-0-x/

Comment: @jmdon  has nothing to do with a cookie. before any cookie is issued, I just need to type the domain and render the view page for login. the question I m having is about how to set attribute routing for razor libraries for identity. ( thank you )

Comment: The reason I mentioned it, is that if you're using cookie authentication then your login page will need to check the cookie in order to render the view.

Comment: I did further research. what i want to do is not really supported yet in the new identity.

Answer (score 0):

I did further research. What I want to do is not really supported yet in the new identity.

[Issue link for those looking for more information.](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1815)